# MVC 5 View with IList time picker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```js
@model IList<LC.Models.Locations>

@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#FromTime').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: '@Model.StartTime',(how do I change here)
                format: 'LT',
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top',
                stepping: 15
            });

        $('#ToTime').datetimepicker({
                defaultDate: '@Model.EndTime',
                format: 'LT',
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top',
                stepping: 15
            });

        });
    </script>
}


 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
 {
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime)
             // How do I change here
             <div class="col-md-10">
                 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromTime, new
                 {
                     htmlAttributes = new
                     {
                         @Value = Model.FromTime.ToString(),
                         @class = "form-control"
                      }
                 })
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FromTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].ToTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how do I add time picker with IList (@model IList). This time picker will work only @model LC.Models.Locations. Could you please tell me how do I modify jQuery for the IList.

This is my jQuery code

Comment: You model is `IList<Locations>` and `IList` does not have a property named `FromTime`. Does `Locations` contain a property named `FromTime`?

Comment: IList<LC.Models.Locations> has FromTime

Comment: FromTime and ToTime both properties.

Comment: Unclear what you trying to do. You need `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime)` which you already have. What are you trying to do with `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromTime...)`?

Comment: This is @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromTime...) working for me. What I need to do change this code to IList.

Comment: @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
 {
     <tr>
         <td>
             @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime)
             // How do I add time picker here...
            
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].ToTime)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

Comment: What do you mean? Using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FromTime...) ` will NOT work because you model is `IList<Locations>`! You need `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime)` and add a class name using `htmlAttributes` (say `@class = "date"`) and then use `$('.date').datetimepicker({...`

Comment: IList<Locations>  defaultDate:
 what do I have add defaultDate:?

Comment: You don't. It is already the value of the date in the model. Just remove `defaultDate: '@Model.StartTime'`

Comment: Thanks, Do I need set Value?   @Value = FromTime,

Comment: Absolutely not (you never set the `value` attribute when using the HtmlHelpers. I will add a answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is `IList<Locations>` and `IList` does not contain a property `FromTime` so `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FromTime)` will generate an error.

You need to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime)` in the `for` loop and give the control a class name so that you can attach the datetimepicker based on the class name. Note that you should never set the `value` attribute when using HtmlHelpers

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].FromTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date" }} )
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].FromTime, new { @class = "text-danger" })
  // ditto for property ToTime
}
```

Then adjust the script to

```
$('.date').datetimepicker({
  format: 'LT',
  showClose: true,
  showClear: true,
  toolbarPlacement: 'top',
  stepping: 15
);
```

Note, the script will attach the plugin to all elements with `class="date"`. You also need to remove the `defaultDate: '@Model.StartTime',` line in your script

Comment: Thank you for your update code, I have some issue without Value with string it is not working. how can I add  Value= FromTime.ToString(),

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If class `Locations` has property `public DateTime FromTime { get; set; }` and you set that to a value (say `DateTime.Now()`, then that will be displayed in the datepicker (your input will be `<input type="text" name="[0].FromTime" value="09/15/2015" />` (depending on you culture). You never set the `value` attribute - the HtmlHelper does that correctly)

Comment: my property public string FromTime { get; set; } because I need only insert table to time value from time picker eg. 8.30AM

Comment: Unhandled exception at line 436, column 21 in http://localhost:51493/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
if (parent.length === 0) {
                    throw new Error('datetimepicker component should be placed within a relative positioned container');
                }

Comment: Your property needs to be `DateTime`, not a string!

Comment: but I need to only insert time valve no need to insert date. Is that bootstrap-datetimepicker.js not support string field?

Comment: Its a **date**timepicker, not a timepicker :). Use another plugin (e.g. [this one](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/) or [this one](http://timepicker.co/))

Comment: It has time timepicker too, because I added same @model TC.Models.TimeLocations it work for me. I use this url http://www.skimedic.com/blog/post/2015/04/03/Using-a-DateTime-Picker-for-ASPNET-MVC-5-with-Bootstrap.aspx